# How to aggs for group by result in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

There is an index: person

```
"_source" : {
  "id" : 304028598,
  "name" : "aaa"   
},
```

want to get these information:
1. average count per name
2. max count one name can have

For sql I could get these info by below sql

```
select max(count), avg(count), min(count) from (
    select name, count(*) count from t group by name
);
```

but how to implement it by elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question relies on [Pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html) -- these aggregations operate on the output of another aggregation.

For example, we have many documents, each with a different `hostVersion` and use the following to find the max, min and average number of documents per host version:

```
"aggs": {
    "per_hostver": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "hostVersion"
      }
    },
    "avg_docs_per_version": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "per_hostver>_count"
      }
    },
    "max_docs_per_version": {
      "max_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "per_hostver>_count"
      }
    },
    "min_docs_per_version": {
      "min_bucket": {
         "buckets_path": "per_hostver>_count"
      }
    }
}
```

The syntax `per_hostver>_count` refers to the `_count` field generated by each bucket of the aggregation `per_hostver`. `_count` is how you refer to the special document count field generated by all ES aggregations.

Comment: Thanks! but I found it's not what I want, it gives me just the first page aggs result, not the whole, just like `select max(count), avg(count), min(count) from ( select name, count(*) count from t group by name order by count(*) desc limit 10);    `

Comment: If the number of groups ("names" in your case) is not too large (say, less than 10K), I think you can add a `size` parameter to the `terms` aggregation.